# MongoNetworkError: connection 0 to localhost:27017 closed

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I can´t get this to work. I have opened mongo and mongod, and this is what I get when I write "node server.js" in git Bash or cmd:

```
Running on server27017
Not connected to database MongoNetworkError: connection 0 to localhost:27017 
closed
```

and here is my code.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = 27017;

//Route
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello world!');
});


const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const option = {
    socketTimeoutMS: 30000,
    keepAlive: true,
    reconnectTries: 30000
};

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/database1', option).then(function(){
    //connected successfully
    console.log('Successfully connected to database');
}, function(err) {
    //err handle
    console.log('Not connected to database ' + err);
});

//Listen to port
app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Running on server' + port);
});
```

and when I write "http://localhost:27017/database1" in the browser I get "It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Express port shouldn't be the same port with mongodb

Answer (score 3):

If you are connecting to mlab and this error is because you have to add your system IP address.

You can add your system's IP address in Network Access tab